# How to set sun grid engine scheduling policy to satisfy this?

Tags: scheduler, policy, sungridengine

We use sun grid engine(actually open scheduler grid) as drms. Suppose we have 3 users: uA, uB, uC. 
uA submit 100000 jobs then uB submit 10 jobs then uC submit 1 job. With default scheduling policy, grid engine will run uA's 100000 jobs and then uB's 10 and then uC's 1 job, thus uB and uC need to wait a long time.

We hope the scheduler can select jobs to run like this:

first, select 1 uA's job, 1 uB's job, 1 uC's job

then, select 19 uA's jobs, 19 uB's jobs

then, select uA's other jobs

How to set the policy to fit this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have done this by setting up a share tree policy with a single user = default. You also need to set a rapid half-life decay on prioritization (I used 1 hour). Also, place 0 priority weight on job waiting time. (Put 100% on the share tree policy.) I did this poking around in qmon and experimenting with different values.